# bluecove on windows vista

Tags: bluetooth, windows-vista, bluecove

I am trying to connect to a remote device via Winsock on Windows Vista, but am getting this error:

> ```
> javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException: 
> at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.connect(Native Method)
> at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.access$700(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:44)
> at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:651)
> ```

I use BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT. Anybody help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

using widcomm bluetooth driver instead of bluecove,
because bluecove does not support l2cap on winsock.